# Is this a transitive relation

Tags: relations

I found this in a web site

If $A = \{ 1, 2, 3\}$, then the relation $R = \{(2, 3)\}$ is not transitive.

Why it is not transitive?

The definition is if whenever an element $a$ is related to an element $b$, and $b$ is in turn related to an element $c$, then $a$ is also related to $c$.
In $R$ there is no matching pair for $(2,3)$, so transitivity can not be checked.

As the ordered pair in $R$ does not violate the condition, can't we say it is transitive?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is transitive, and vacuously so.

Comment: Can you post the link to that web site?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed transitive.
This is true vacuously; we need to check that if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, then $(a,c)\in R$.
But there are no two pairs $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$, so the required condition indeed holds for all such pairs (since there are none).
I would prefer to say that transitivity *can* be checked, but there is nothing to check; not checking and checking the empty set are different things, for me at least.